# Playing AVI files in macOS using VLC

Tags: video, quicktime, vlc

On Ubuntu, I use VLC to play all types of videos. Now I have a MacBook Air I bought in 2017 with macOS High Sierra. I tried to play an AVI file, but QuickTime does not recognize the format. There is no other app it offers in Applications. So I tried searching for VLC on the App Store but unable to find it.

How can I play AVI videos, which QuickTime does not recognize on macOS? Why isn't VLC on the App Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VLC for macOS is available and is regularly updated, just like VLC for Ubuntu. If you can play a file using VLC in Ubuntu, it can also be played by VLC on macOS.

You can download VLC for macOS [here](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html).

Clicking the download button will download a `.dmg` file in `Downloads` folder in Finder. To install VLC, simply double-click the `.dmg` file. A DMG file is identified as **Apple Disk Image** in macOS and is mounted as a volume in Finder. To install VLC simply copy `VLC.app` by dragging it into the `/Applications` directory.

[image]

Alternatively, if you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) setup (a popular package manager for macOS), you can install VLC using [Homebrew Cask](https://caskroom.github.io) by running:

`brew cask install vlc`

VLC for macOS is not distributed via Mac App Store. Unlike iOS App Store, Mac App Store isn't the only option to install apps in macOS. A lot of developers choose to distribute their apps independently.

Comment: "Unlike iOS App Store" – Not true

Comment: "Not true"? In what way?